# How to change time configuration?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

Is it possible to change the configuration of the date(); that's already been inserted into the database?

For example:
right now the date is displayed in the following way: December 12th 2013 12:28pm

Is there a way to display only the parts i choose from it? like "12 DEC".

Trying to get this done in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `date()`? You mentioned it in your question.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html could be of assistance depending if you want it a global change, or specific to a query

Comment: You said how your dates are displayed, but you didn't mentioned how you actually store them. What is the exact data type that is used for this column in your table?

Comment: its stored in a VARCHAR table and inserted as $date = date("F jS, Y, g:i a");

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date()` function. If you're trying to format the value from a database entry, fetch it and display it using `strtoupper(date('j M',strtotime($row['column'])))` (which will output the format you're looking for and capitalize everything like the example you provided)

Answer (score 1):

Don't store date/time values (especially verbosely formatted) as strings in the database, because you loose the ability to normally maintain and query your data. Use appropriate date [data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) for that (`DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or even `INT` if you store Unix epoch time in seconds).

You can change the datatype from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME` in a following way

```sql
UPDATE table_name
   SET column_name = STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%M %D, %Y, %h:%i %p');
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name DATETIME;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6b31/1)** demo

Now you can properly and easily filter and order your data by `date` column, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name >= '2013-12-17'
   AND column_name < '2013-12-18'
 ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```

Now you can easily present your datetime values as you need with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function e.g.:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d %b') formatted_date
  FROM table_name;
```

Sample output:

```
| FORMATTED_DATE |
|----------------|
|         17 Dec |
|         18 Dec |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6b31/5)** demo

---

In the meantime if you need an immediate solution you can do

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%M %D, %Y, %h:%i %p'), '%d %b') formatted_date
  FROM table_name;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3953/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

To get date with your format, you will try:

```
<?php
echo date('d M');
?>
```

But, you need update each row in your table to change their value.